# Yum Update breaks ssh on SELinux Policy Package

Tags: google-compute-engine

On a brand new Centos Box in Google Compute Engine I decided to do a yum update before moving forward to insure everything was at the latest revisions.

On the step for updating selinux-policy-targeted the box then locks me out. SSH connection dies there, and no new connections are accepted. I had set SElinux to permissive before doing the updates but that did not seem to stick through the update. Rebooting is of no use, has to destroy and re-create the box.

Anyway around this other than just simply blacklisting selinux related items?

Thank you,

Michael

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue.

There is a way around this, albeit not hugely ideal - remove selinux before running yum update.

```
yum remove selinux*
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue with a micro VM.
It hasn't enough memory for patching selinux out of the box.

Either use a bigger VM or enable swap.